# animated transition between an activity and another

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I state that i'm not very experienced in android, and I would like to understand, perhaps with some tutorial, how to implement any scrolling animation between one activity and another. I hope in your help

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can set up animations (like slide) when you switch between activities like this :

In the `res` folder, create an `anim` folder

For example, put two `xml` files for a slide effect :

slide_in.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate 
       android:fromXDelta="100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
       android:fromYDelta="0%"   android:toYDelta="0%"
       android:duration="200"/>
</set>
```

slide_out.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
       android:fromXDelta="100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
       android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
       android:duration="200" />
</set>
```

Then on your java code just write this :

```
Intent i = new Intent(YourActivity.this, OtherActivity.class);
this.startActivity(i);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
```

If you are testing that on a real device, don't forget to allow it to play animations (Settings -> Display -> Animations -> All Animations)

Hope it helps ! :)

Comment: thanks for the advice,
I'm testing, but I have a small problem, the transition from one activity to another is after pressing a button and I have do  "finish();" on the activity starting

Comment: Which activity do you want to finish ? The first one ?

Comment: I edited my answer. Is it working like you want now ?

Comment: Now the activity is not even started

Comment: the first activity don't start

Comment: Please put the code of the button event.

Comment: But If you call finish() on your first activity, it destroys it.

Comment: In fact, I have to destroy the first activated and move to the second

Comment: If you call finish() on your first activity, you won't be able to start it a second time. Finish : `Call this when your activity is done and should be closed`. See this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html and this http://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png to understand how activities works.

Comment: I added the above code but by second activity is not displaying. :(

Comment: @SiKni8 Any error in logcat ?

Comment: Do we have to have a Material Theme in our styles.xml? Or at least be using API 21 or higher?