# How to transition from one screen to next with animation

Tags: android, android-animation, android-transitions

I just looked at the twitter app and it seems to have a nice sliding transition while moving from one screen to the next. I'm trying to get the same behavior in my app.

Currently I move between screens with:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyActivity.class), 1);
```

But this way there is no transition between the screen. The `MyActivity` just pops up on the screen.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12092894/animated-transition-between-an-activity-and-another

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Animations with drawables:**

[This tutorial](http://www.41post.com/3368/programming/android-changing-the-animation-between-activities) might help you to understand how it works. First, you should create a folder named `anim` in `/res/` folder. Then, create and put into it the `drawables` which will be uses to make a transition animation as follows:

*anim_left_to_right.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate 
        android:fromXDelta="-100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
</set>
```

*anim_right_to_left.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate 
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="-100%"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
</set>
```

Then, use [`overridePendingTransition()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition%28int,%20int%29) method to call the drawables and apply them to the *startActivity()* (or *startActivityForResult()*) method:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyActivity.class), 1);
overridePendingTransition(anim_left_to_right, anim_right_to_left);
```

**Custom animations relative to lifecycle:**

You can also make custom animations, "regardless startActivity method", but in using the lifecycle of activities: I mean like `Vine` when you call the enter animation into `onCreate()` and the out animation into `onPause()`. This is [a great demo](http://blog.quent.in/index.php/2013/06/activity-transition-animations-like-the-vine-android-application/) about this kind of feature.

Comment: That works fine. How about when I go back from second activity back to first activity. I do that with: setResult(RESULT_OK, mainIntent); finish();

Comment: @Anthony do the same, or use `onResume` method into first Activity to make a custom animation and `onPause` for the previous one, like the example for Vine, when you come back.

Answer (score 3):

Call **`overridePendingTransition(entry_anim, exit_anim)`** after calling the startActivity().

You can specify the entry and exit animations through xml.

Comment: That works fine. How about when I go back from second activity back to first activity. I do that with: `setResult(RESULT_OK, mainIntent); finish();`

Comment: Call the same snippet after calling finish.