# How can I animate the opening of a secondary android activity? as on playstore news

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

Although I do know how to open another activity quite easily, using intent like the below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(first.this, second.class);                                   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
intent.putExtra("selectedApp", ApplicationTitle.getText());
startActivity(intent);
```

When you use the android application "PlayStore News", when you select a news item rather than just being redirected to another activity. An animation occurs, where in the change between several small cards to one large occurs.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12092894/animated-transition-between-an-activity-and-another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.mysamplecode.com/2013/02/android-animation-switching-activity.html

There is a method

```
 overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_up_in, R.anim.push_up_out);
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html#Transitions

This explains how to define custom transitions between activities. In particular, you may be interested in shared element transitions. I'd be more specific, but its a fairly broad question

Answer (score 0):

Check this sample code for animation while switching activities in android.

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/04/custom-animation-while-switching.html
http://www.mysamplecode.com/2013/02/android-animation-switching-activity.html